# Using $translate in a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-translate

I am making a filter that translates the given key. The filter will translate a value using `Drupal.t()` if the function exists else it will use The Angular Translate from Pascal Precht.

For angular translate I am using the static file loader

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'assets/i18n/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

My config :

```
.config(['$logProvider', '$translateProvider', '$compileProvider', function($logProvider, $translateProvider, $compileProvider) {
    var debug = true;
    // turn debug logging on or off in console
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(debug);

    // turn on debug data
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(debug);

    // configure the translator tables
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'assets/i18n/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    // configure what language to use based on the html lang attribute
    $translateProvider.use(document.documentElement.lang);

    // configure fallback language
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');

    // sanitizes HTML in the translation text
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
}])
```

The run method decides wether or not to use `Drupal.t()`.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$log', function($rootScope, $log) {
    // set language
    $rootScope.lang = document.documentElement.lang;
    // set default lang
    if (!$rootScope.lang) {
        $rootScope.lang = 'en';
    }
    // set environment
    $log.debug("Lang is "+$rootScope.lang);

    // check if translation should be done by drupal
    $rootScope.translator = 'angular';
    if (typeof Drupal !== 'undefined') {
        // drupal exists so check if the t function is available
        if (typeof Drupal.t === "function") {
            // safe to use the function
            $log.debug("Drupal t present");
            $rootScope.translator = 'drupal';
        }
    }
}]);
```

So far so good. Now to translate my keys I need to use a custom filter. In the filter I want to look If I should use `Drupal.t()` or angular translate.

My filter :

```
.filter('translator', ['$filter', '$rootScope', '$translate', function($filter, $rootScope, $translate) {
    return function(input) {
        input = input || '';
        var out = '';

        // if possible use the drupal translator
        if ($rootScope.translator === 'drupal') {
            out = Drupal.t(input);
        } else {
            // fallback to default angular translator
            //var $translate = $filter('translate');
            out = $filter('translate')(input);
        }

        return out;
    }
}]);
```

My problem is that `$filter('translate')(input);` always returns the key itself. I can't get a translation out of it.

Comment: I am not sure. But I think the config phase is before the run phase. so in theory the angular provider has no idea which language to choose. the language should be clear in the config phase If I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Daniel Well my config is configured for that. I guess I just put the lang on the rootScope to log it. Good point though. (See question again for my config)

Comment: Have ypu tried to use `$translate.instant(input)` instead of `$filter('translate')(input)`. Or if you do `$translate(input).then(function(label) {console.log(label})` what do you see in your console ?

Comment: @Tako Using `instant(input)` just returns the key. Using the promise Actually works! But the views `{{ 'TEST' | translator}}` does not get updated I guess because it is blank.

Comment: Ok so if ther promise works I think the problem comes from your json file isn't loaded yet when your filter is called.
Maybe you can try to make your filter $stateful, so the value returned by your filter will be updated on each digest  (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters).
I think it's no really an elegant way to to it, but it should work

Comment: @Tako Yes, it worked. But you are right. I think it is better to solve my problem with a directive. By using a directive I wont have that lag on startup that shows my translate keys.

Comment: Yes I think it's better to create a directive